# Using tidyr::pivot_wider when some keys have multiple values

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a long data frame that i want to widen, but one key has two different values:

```
df <- data.frame(ColA=c("A", "B", "B", "C"), ColB=letters[23:26])

  ColA ColB
1    A    w
2    B    x
3    B    y
4    C    z
```

I want my output to be a paste of the two values for this key together:

```
  ColA ColB
1    A    w
2    B    xy
3    C    z
```

A regular `pivot_wider()` will throw a warning and convert the values to lists:

```
df.wide <- df %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from=ColA, values_from=ColB)

Warning message:
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates 

# A tibble: 1 x 3
  A         B         C        
  <list>    <list>    <list>   
1 <chr [1]> <chr [2]> <chr [1]>
```

Based on the warning it looks like `pivot_wider()` with a `value_fn()` is similar to what I want as an intermediate step:

```
# intermediate step
df.wide <- df %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from=ColA, values_from=ColB, values_fn=SOMETHING)

   A  B  C
1  w  xy z
```

But it looks like `values_fn()` only takes summary functions, and not something that would work on character data (like `paste()`)

The closest I can get is:

```
df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=ColA, values_from=ColB, values_fn=list) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=everything(), names_to="ColA", values_to="ColB")

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  ColA  ColB             
  <chr> <chr>            
1 A     "w"              
2 B     "c(\"x\", \"y\")"
3 C     "z"
```

With an additional mutating `gsub()`-type function. Surely there's an easier way! Preferably within the `tidyverse`, but also open to other packages.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to pivot here, unless your real data is more complicated than the example shown.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ColA) %>% 
  summarise(ColB = paste0(ColB, collapse = ""))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  ColA  ColB 
  <chr> <chr>
1 A     w    
2 B     xy   
3 C     z
```

Comment: ... it's been a long day. Thanks for this super simple solution.